# Displaying Images on List View

Tags: list-view, images

Is there an easy way to display an image that's related to a record within a list view? The image would be different for each record. An example would be having a list of homes with an image of the front of each home.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to use a rich text area or formula field in a list view.

Comment: Is it possible to do it dynamically? Trying to figure out the best way to store the image and display it on the record.

Comment: @sfdcfox - I tried both of your solutions, rich text did not display the image on the listview but the formula did. I used a custom text field to hold the URL of the image stored in Files, then referenced that field in the IMAGE function of another field. I don't want to have to manually add the URL of the image to the record each time, so I'll need to figure out how that process can be eliminated. Thank you for the input it was much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To display images in a list view you need first to have them in a field. It can be either a rich text field or a formula field.
In case of a rich text field you have the choice to upload the image to the rich text or to populate the rich text with HTML referencing the URL of the image.
In case of a Formula field you can use the IMAGE formula referencing the URL of the image.
If the image is stored as a file/doc/attachement in Salesforce you need some automation to extract the resulting image URL which permits to display it and insert it as an image or a URL in a rich text field or save it in a URL field to be used in the formula field.
If you are open to use App from the AppExchange, you can also rely on App such as SharinPix which automates all that for you (upload a picture, tag it will save it as a resized version URL in a field so it can be rendered into List View/Report and more).

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Show images in list view feature isn't available at moment.  Kindly review [Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdeXeUAJ/show-images-in-list-view) and vote for this feature.  Also, there is a workaround mentioned in comments and see if that works for you.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the response. I ended up using a combination of fields and formula field to display on the list view.